# Requests not loading the content as web Browser gives Python

Tags: python, python-requests, request

Hay ! I am new here so let me describe clearly my issue,Please Ignore mistakes.
I am making request on a page which literlaly works on js.
Acually its the page of paytm payemnt response through UPI.

When ever i do the requests the response is {'POLL_STATUS':"STOP_POLLING"}

But the problem is the reqest is giving this response while the browser is giving another response with loaded html.

I tried everyting like stopeed redirects and printing raw content nothing works.
I just think may be urllib post request may be work but i do not know the uses.

Can anyone please tell me how to get the exact html response as the browser gives.

Note[0]:Please dont provide answer of selenium because this issue having in the middle of my script.
Note[1]:Friendly answer appriciated.

```
for i in range(0,15):
        resp_check_transaction=self.s.post("https://secure.website.in/theia/upi/transactionStatus?MID="+str(Merchant_ID)+"&ORDER_ID="+str(ORDER_ID),headers=check_transaction(str(ORDER_ID)),data=check_transaction_payload(Merchant_ID,ORDER_ID,TRANSID,CASHIERID))
        print(resp_check_transaction.text)
        resp_check_transaction=resp_check_transaction.json()
        if resp_check_transaction['POLL_STATUS']=="STOP_POLLING":
            
            print("Breaking looop")
            break
        time.sleep(4)
    self.clear_header()
    parrms={
        "MID": str(Merchant_ID),
        "ORDER_ID": str(ORDER_ID)
    }
    resp_transaction_pass=requests.post("https://secure.website.in/theia/upi/transactionStatus",headers=transaction_pass(str(ORDER_ID)),data=transaction_pass_payload(CASHIERID,UPISTATUSURL,Merchant_ID,ORDER_ID,TRANSID,TXN_AMOUNT),params=parrms,allow_redirects=True)
    print("Printing response")
    print(resp_transaction_pass.text)
    print(resp_transaction_pass.content)
```

And in the web browser its showing that Status Code: 302 Moved Temporarily in the bank response of Bank response. :(

Comment: It's rather difficult to help you without any code to look at, could you maybe share spinets of the Python and JS code so we can see the differences?

Comment: @Matt Updated . Can you please check...

Answer (score 0):

## About the 302 status code

You mention that the web browser is sends a 302 status code in response to the request. In the simplest terms the 302 status code is just the web servers way of saying "Hey I know what you're looking for but it is actually located at this other URL.".

Basically all modern browsers and HTTP request libraries like Python's `Requests` will automatically follow a 302 redirect and act as though you send the request to the new URL instead. (Your browser's developer tools may show that a 302 redirect has happened but as far as the JavaScript is concerned it just got a normal `200` response).

If you really want to see if your Python script receives a 302 status you can do so by setting the `allow_redirects` option to `False`, but this means you will manually have to get the stuff from the new URL.

```py
import requests

r1 = requests.get('https://httpstat.us/302', allow_redirects=False)
r2 = requests.get('https://httpstat.us/302', allow_redirects=True)

print('No redirects:', r1.status_code)     # 302
print('Redirects on:', r2.status_code)     # 200 (status code of page it redirects to)
```

*Note that `allow_redirects` is already set to `True` by default, I just wanted to make the example a bit more verbose so the difference is obvious.*

## So why is the response content different?

So even though the browser and the `Requests` library are both automatically following the 302 redirect the response they get is still different, you didn't share any screenshots of the browsers requests or responses so I can only give a few educated guesses but it boils down to the fact that the request made by your Python code is somehow different from the JavaScript loaded by the web browser.

Some things to consider:

- Are you sure you are using the he correct HTTP method? Is the browser also making a POST request?
- If so are you sure the body of the request is the same/of the same format as the one sent by the web browser?
- Perhaps the browser has a session cookie it is sending along with the request (Note this usually not explicitly said in the JS but happens automatically).
- Alternatively the JS might include some API key/credentials in the HTTP auth header (this should be explicitly visible in JS).
- **Although unlikely** it could be that whatever API you're trying to query is trying to block reverse engineering attempts by blocking the `Requests` library's user agent string.

Luckily all of these differences can be easily examined with some print statements and your browser's developer tools :p.